# my url in django doesn't return HTTPResponse?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

there is a problem with a url i've created in django that it doesn't totally work
this is urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from pizza import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('', views.home,name='home'),
    url('order/', views.order,name='order'),
]
```

and this is views.py

```
   from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Home page")
def order(request):
    return HttpResponse("Order a pizza page")
```

Answer (score 0):

That is incorrect syntax, try using path('') instead of url

Answer (score 0):

If `pizza` it's your app you must use:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path, include 
urlpatterns = [    
    path('pizza/', include('pizza.urls')),
]
```

in urls.py and add your app in settings.py inside `INSTALLED_APPS`

OR

If when you call `from pizza import views` is the name of Project you should import as `import .views` only

Answer (score -1):

Update in project urls.py file.

Comment: Asking the questioner to read a tutorial, isn't addressing the coding issue. Code has been shown, where it is clear what the error is. Please identify the coding error, and you can supplement the fix with a link to a tutorial for background information.